# Heroku, node.js: stop downloading node_modules on each deploy

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-modules

Currently Heroku reinstalls all dependencies each time I deploy my app. It can possibly break something if a new version of a dependency has a bug or not compatible with my current setup. Is there a way to tell heroku to download dependencies only when I change version in the package.js (just like they do it on dotCloud)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a bug in Heroku, the way to block a package is to use a specific version of your dependencies inside your `package.json`. Take a look at the [node.js page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm).

sample `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.5.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aliem. Heroku is still downloading dependencies on each deploy, but at least the versions don't change.